# Не открывается ссылка на файл с другого сервера

Tags: javascript, html

Генерация ссылки в js

переменная patch содержит путь \xx.xx.xxx.xxx\name.pfg

```
dwb= "<td><a href='file://"+patch+"'class='btn btn-success' target='_blank'>Скачать</a>";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере ссылка имеет следующий вид

При клике на ссылку ничего не происходит. Я уже пробовал и три слеша ставить, и четеры.. и обратные слеши тоже :( ничего не помогает...

Answer (score 0):

js работает только в пределах домена страницы. Т.е. Если у вас страница на [www.aaa.com](http://www.aaa.com) скачать файл с [www.bbb.com](http://www.bbb.com) не получится. Я вышел из этой ситуации созданием PHP кода, который принимает url файла, скачивает его и отдает js